# slf4j logger singleton issue

Tags: java, log4j, singleton, slf4j

I want to do logging using `slf4j`. I write my own logger class

```
public class GlobalLogger {
   private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalLogger.class);
   public static void logApplicationLog(String message) {
     logger.info("[" + APPLICATION_LOG + "]" + message);
   }
}
```

I use pattern layout in log4j so that in log `%C` display class as `GlobalLogger` but I want that `%C` should display the calling class. How do I do that with condition that object of logger should be singleton in whole application?

Comment: But `GlobalLogger` *is* the calling class. The question is: why do you need that to be a singleton when you can get Loggers anywhere you need them?

Comment: As you can see in method, I've added my static message. I want to classify my info messages in different categories so I put my own static message in method. This kind of four other methods are in the class. This is the actual purpose of this class.

Comment: Then why don't you `LoggerFactory.getLogger(APPLICATION_LOG)`? And create appenders for each of the Categories with a static text added in the pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Write a wrapper over the logger class , which will act as a singleton class. Like :

```
public class Logger{

private static Logger logger;    
private Logger(){
}
public synchronized static Logger getLogger()
    {
        if (logger!= null)
            return logger;
        return logger=LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalLogger.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are not using `name` in that snippet!?

Comment: Edited. Initially I was thing of passing that name parameter to getLogger method, which can be done if needed.

Comment: This gives me singleton object every time but still `%C` prints the `GlobalLogger` **not name of my calling class**

Comment: It will give you the same object everytime. And modify it and pass the name of your calling class in getLogger(String name)..Can you share your code of the calling class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a shorthand for creating a logger and putting a message to it:

```
public class GlobalLogger {

   public static void logApplicationLog( String message, Class source ) {
     LoggerFactory.getLogger(source).info("[" + APPLICATION_LOG + "]" + message);
   }

}
```

I don't know of a possibility to inject a source on a "per message" basis, though there may be one.

*Note:* I recommend using a static Logger instance in each class that is supposed to log something rather than the code I gave above. You could even change your IDE's template for creating new clases to already include that for you.

**EDIT**

I see you want to put a static portion to create "Categories" (as to your comments above).

Then why don't you `LoggerFactory.getLogger(APPLICATION_LOG)` and create appenders for each of the Categories with a static text added in the pattern? Or do you have to be able to change logLevels by packages?